# Webmethods - Can it host its own web services?

Tags: java, web-services, webmethods

Webmethods Integration Server can integrate systems and orchestrate different web services from external systems on the network.

My question is: Is it possible to create Java code running in Webmethods Integration Server, and expose it as a web service? Therefore, having Webmethods host the web service.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

yes that's possible. You can use a Java service inside IS to code your logic. You have to define an interface for this service (a doctype). After this is done, you create a webservice provider that calls your service.
This applies to IS from version 7 upwards.

Comment: Can I call a webMethods flow service from a Java application?

Comment: Yes. That's possible, but you have to include an IS library to call the flow services. You would need classes like:  com.wm.app.b2b.client.Context and call the invoke() method.

Answer (score 3):

Absolutely, that's one of the core purposes of the platform.

To expose any service (flow, java, adapter service etc) you need to create a web service connector (of type "Provider") and then drag the services you want to expose onto it. You can then point to the WSDL it generates.

The approach of webMethods to have everything as a service means that any code you write on the Integration Server can be added to one of these providers and thus invoked as a web service.

You can also proxy other web services (e.g. the wrap and layer approach) by building a web service connector (Provider) using an existing WSDL. What it will then do is mimic the existing WSDL and allow you to provide an implementation of it.